# Simple Form & Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, devise, simple-form

I'm using simple form and devise in my rails app (hosted on heroku).

I have a user model which has a 'registration_role' attribute.

I added the following to my registration form:

```
 <%= f.input :registration_role do %>
 <%= f.select :registration_role, (['Student', 'Educator']), include_blank: true %>
  <% end %>
```

Whilst it works when i run local host, it doesn't work when i push to heroku. I get  a no method error on registration role.

Does anyone know what I've done wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Did you run heroku run rake db:migrate ?

Comment: Hi - is there a command for 'heroku run rake db:migrate" ? as opposed to just 'rake db:migrate'

Comment: Yes you need to migrate you database to production, try it and see

Comment: Hi, I now get this error: unexpected ',', expecting => (somewhere around where it says 'included blank'